# Getting distorted sound if changing rate of audio using AVAudioPlayerNode and AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I want to change rate and pitch of audio file. when i'm changing rate of audio pitch automatically changing and getting not clear sound of audio.

i'm using this code

```
var engine: AVAudioEngine!
var player: AVAudioPlayerNode!
var pitch : AVAudioUnitTimePitch!
var file = AVAudioFile()
var totalDuration : TimeInterval!


 func configurePlayer() {
        engine = AVAudioEngine()
        player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        player.volume = 1.0

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "wav") 
        let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!) 

        file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
        do {
            try file.read(into: buffer!)
        } catch _ {
        }

        pitch = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()

        pitch.rate = 1

        engine.attach(player)

        engine.attach(pitch)
        engine.attach(speedEffect)


        engine.connect(player, to: pitch, format: buffer?.format)

        engine.connect(pitch, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: buffer?.format)

        player.scheduleBuffer(buffer!, at: nil, options: AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferOptions.loops, completionHandler: nil)

        engine.prepare()
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch _ {
        }
    }




@IBAction func slideValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let newRate = sender.value/120;
        pitch.rate = newRate
    }
```

when changing rate using slider getting bad sound.

```
 slider minValue: 60  maxValue: 240
```

Comment: I have a old swift project (maybe swift1) which done a very similar thing, it might help you, checkout this file: https://github.com/martinjkelly/pitch-perfect/blob/master/Pitch%20Perfect/PlaybackViewController.swift

Comment: you are changing rate using AVAudioPlayer but i'm using AVAudioPlayerNode.
I want both option in my audio pitch change and rate change.

Comment: using avaudio player i can change only rate of audio not pitch. so i'm getting bad voice when use AVAudioPlayerNode